# SQL case statement to a better C# method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.5

I have code in SQL that will take the length of a SMS message and tell me how many parts the message will be.

Messages <= 160 characters are one part.

Messages > 160 characters become multipart messages, each part will then contain 152 characters. Can somebody please help me figure out a decent algorithm to accomplish something similar to the following in C# (lambda and linq expressions are welcome):

```
select  
    (case 
        when (LEN(Message)<=160) then 1
        when (LEN(Message)>160 and LEN(Message)<305) then 2
        when (LEN(Message)>304 and LEN(Message)<457) then 3
        when (LEN(Message)>456 and LEN(Message)<609) then 4
        when (LEN(Message)>608 and LEN(Message)<761) then 5
        when (LEN(Message)>760 and LEN(Message)<913) then 6
        when (LEN(Message)>912 and LEN(Message)<1065) then 7
        when (LEN(Message)>1064 and LEN(Message)<1217) then 8
        when (LEN(Message)>1216 and LEN(Message)<1369) then 9
        when (LEN(Message)>1368 and LEN(Message)<1521) then 10
        else 'n'
    end) as [Msg Parts]
from tblAuditLog
```

Comment: 1 + ((LEN(Message)-160) / 152)?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - If it is multipart then ALL message parts have a 152 limit, even the first.

Comment: @Ste D'oh! Indeed, my bad hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(message.Length <= 160) ? 1 : (message.Length + 151) / 152)
```

assumes the message is a string named `message`. It takes care of rounding up (via the `+ 151`) and uses integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it in your SQL? It really doesn't matter but you have no need to list out all the cases when it's a matter of simple division:

```
1+ (LEN(Message)-160)/152 AS [Msg Parts]
```

I'm not familiar with how division is handled in your SQL so you should also round up (LEN(Message)-160)/152 just to be safe.

Comment: This is a C# question, not a SQL question. The SQL code is just the "specification" of the requirement.

Comment: I don't have an issue with your answer, it's definitely correct. I just wanted to provide this option in case he overlooked it. I recognize that yours is the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a raw translation, try:

```
from n in tblAuditLog
select new
{
    Parts = 
    (
        n.Length <= 160 ? 1 :
        n.Length > 160 ? 2 :
        n.Lenth > 304 ? 3 :
        //and so on
    )
}
```